# Joining 3 tables and removing nulls from 2nd and 3rd table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I would like to join 3 tables and remove null in second and third tables where records doesn't match due to join. I kind of got the result but not able to remove null and hence why when I take this query into SSRS I am losing a record.

Here are my 3 tables and result what I am getting.

Table A

[image]

Table B

[image]

Table C

[image]

Current results What I am getting with following query

[image]

My query is as follows from which I am getting above result in blue.

```
SELECT     
    d.ProviderName, d.Service, d.ClientName, d.[StartDate&Time], 
    d.Duration, d.Status, d.VisitTyoe, 
    i.IndirectType, i.IndirectScheduleStart, i.IndirectStatus, i.IndirectDuration,
    e.[Date], e.[SubProgram], e.[ApprovedMileage],
    e.[Status], e.[TravelTime], e.[StipendsTravelTime]
FROM         
    V_DirectDetails d 
FULL OUTER JOIN
    V_IndirectDetails i ON d.ProviderName = i.ProviderName
                        AND d.[StartDate&Time] = i.IndirectScheduleStart
FULL OUTER JOIN    
    [dbo].[V_ExpenseDetails] e ON d.ProviderName = e.ProviderName
                               AND d.[StartDate&Time] = e.[Date]
```

When I tried to put this in SSRS report, with following query as Stored Procedure, I am loosing last row.

Here is the SSRS stored procedure query:

```
    @Office NVARCHAR(4000),
    @Servicetype NVARCHAR(4000),
    @Start DATETIME,
    @End DATETIME,
    @employee nvarchar(400)

SELECT     
    d.ProviderName, d.Service as DirectServices, d.ClientName, 
    d.[StartDate&Time] as "DirectStartDate&Time", d.Duration as DirectDuration, 
    d.Status as DirectStatus, d.VisitTyoe as DirectVisittype, 
    i.IndirectType as IndirectVisitType, i.IndirectScheduleStart as "IndirectStartDate&Time", 
    i.IndirectStatus as IndirectStatus, i.IndirectDuration as IndirectDuration,
    e.[Date] as "TravelDate&Time", e.[SubProgram], e.[ApprovedMileage],
    e.[Status] as TravelTimeStatus, e.[TravelTime], e.[StipendsTravelTime]
FROM         
    V_DirectDetails d 
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    V_IndirectDetails i ON d.ProviderName = i.ProviderName
                        AND d.[StartDate&Time] = i.IndirectScheduleStart
FULL OUTER JOIN         
    [dbo].[V_ExpenseDetails] e ON d.ProviderName = e.ProviderName
                               AND d.[StartDate&Time] = e.[Date]
WHERE
    CAST(d.[StartDate&Time] AS DATE) BETWEEN '2016-07-28' AND '2016-07-29'  
    AND d.[siteidname] = 'CountrySide' 
    AND d.title = 'Painter' 
    AND d.ProviderName = 'Peter A'
ORDER BY
    d.ProviderName
```

Here is what I am getting through SSRS query:

[image]

My expected result is to put Table A, B, C side by side without repeating Provider's name and display null/empty in table B's last 2 rows and null in table's C's last 3 rows since Table A has 6, Table B has 4 and Table C has 3 rows.

Please guide, if you can.

Comment: Thanks for editing. I will make sure these changes next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WHERE-condition on `d` changes the result to a `RIGHT JOIN`, try modifying it to:

```
WHERE
 (
    CAST(d.[StartDate&Time] AS DATE) BETWEEN '2016-07-28' AND '2016-07-29'  
    AND d.[siteidname] = 'CountrySide' 
    AND d.title = 'Painter' 
    AND d.ProviderName = 'Peter A'
 ) 
OR d.ProviderName IS NULL
```

or better move the conditions into a *Derived Table*:

```
FROM  
 ( 
    SELECT * 
    FROM V_DirectDetails
    WHERE
       CAST(d.[StartDate&Time] AS DATE) BETWEEN '2016-07-28' AND '2016-07-29'  
       AND d.[siteidname] = 'CountrySide' 
       AND d.title = 'Painter' 
       AND d.ProviderName = 'Peter A'
 ) d 
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    V_IndirectDetails i ON d.ProviderName = i.ProviderName
                        AND d.[StartDate&Time] = i.IndirectScheduleStart
FULL OUTER JOIN         
    [dbo].[V_ExpenseDetails] e ON d.ProviderName = e.ProviderName
                               AND d.[StartDate&Time] = e.[Date]
```

Comment: Thank you '@dnoeth' for your efforts, I am just trying to get this thing done with '@niketshah90' solution since I already started working on it.  I also got the result what I want, but now looks like it's SSRS issue, records starting with null which is 6th records but it does have a data for indirect activities , but it doesn't show at all.

Comment: Hello everyone, so finally I was able to solve this. I am not sure if I mentioned already but It was just cache problem in my SSRS browser, I restarted VS and everything is working that point onwards. Thanks '@dnoeth',@niketshah90 and everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your date filter with    `CAST(coalesce(d.[StartDate&Time],i.IndirectScheduleStart,e.[Date]) AS DATE) BETWEEN '2016-07-28' AND '2016-07-29'`

Comment: it still show only 6 records...:-( . I believe the comma before AS Date is just typo right? because it doesn't allow me to run the store proc.

Comment: Hi, So I have added your solution to other parameters as well as follows,CAST(coalesce(d.[StartDate&Time],i.IndirectScheduleStart,e.[Date]) AS DATE) BETWEEN Start AND end and
coalesce(d.[siteidname],i.[siteidname],e.[siteidname]) = Office and
coalesce(d.title,i.title,e.title)=Servicetype and
coalesce(d.ProviderName,i.ProviderName,e.ProviderName) = employee

Comment: Did that work? basically null values are getting filtered out because u are V_IndirectDetails for your parameter. I think solution provided by @dnoeth should work too

Comment: This works when I run this query in SQL SERVERbut doesn't show up in SSRS , I think now its SSRS issue.

Comment: @user2040021 I believe there is an option in SSRS to exclude/include empty results for a tablix. I could be wrong on that, but you could also try replacing the `NULL` value with some placeholder value so that SSRS doesn't know that it's `NULL` when you run the report.  Wrapping the field(s) with `NULL` value(s) in an `ISNULL` or `COALESCE`.

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping out. it was just cache , I restarted the reports and displayed right results.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `full outer join` with a `left join`.

Comment: It's still missing the 4th record  from Table B where it says "Preparation", since I believe it doesn't not getting matching date and time with Table A.

Answer (score 0):

Brute Force it!

```
UPDATE TABLE SET COL = CASE WHEN COL IS NULL THEN ENTERYOURVALUEHERE ELSE COL END
```

Comment: Wow, that's a ingenious idea, simply modify the data to match your needs. Not. And your statement should be `UPDATE TABLE SET COL = ENTERYOURVALUEHERE WHERE COL IS NULL`

Comment: @dnoeth, you are thee best at everything! Congratulations!!! Pat yourself on the back, you did it!!! Is that sarcasm AND satire?? In one, no... 2 sentences?? NIce!! touché

Comment: You're welcome. Btw, the NULLs were due to the outer joins, how to update those?

Comment: I'd recommend doing it after the join

Comment: Materialize the result in a table and then update it? But the OP had problems to include the rows with NULL in the result set.